# Function turning Factiva-HTML into a tidy-dataframe

Tags: r, merge, tm, corpus, tidytext

Using the tm.plugin.factiva-package I want to create a function that can read Factiva-html files, and return them as a dataframe. So far I've managed to create a function that can read these files, and transform them into a list of dataframes, each df corresponding to one html-file. However, I struggle to find a way in which to merge them into one df, since the `tidy()` function returns certain columns as a list, rather than a character vector.  Using `bind_rows()` f.ex. returns the error `` Error: Column `company` can't be converted from list to character ``. Theoretically all of the columns where this is a problem, could be selected away as I have no real need for them, however I can't find a way to do this for the list as a whole, given that e.g. `select()` cant handle lists (and I'm quite new to utilising them myself).

The function for now looks like this:

```
Factiva_Reader <- function(File_Path){
pac <-  c("tidyverse", "tidytext", "tm", "tm.plugin.factiva")
sapply(pac, require, character.only = TRUE) #Loading required packages,
                                          

Filer <- list.files(File_Path)
Filer <- str_extract(Filer, "\\w*\\.html")
Filer <- Filer[!is.na(Filer)] #Creates a list of all valid files in folder

Data <- sapply(Filer, FactivaSource)
Data <- sapply(Data, Corpus, readerControl = list(language = NA))
Data <- lapply(Data, tidy)
}
```

I was a quite uncertain as to how to show the data since it technically is copyrighted, and in a weird format, this should, however, at least show the structure. So far the function returns a list containing a df in this format for each file in the folder:

```
$ Factiva3.html: tibble [100 x 20] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
..$ author       : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ datetimestamp: POSIXct[1:100], format:  ...
..$ description  : logi [1:100] NULL ...
..$ heading      : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ id           : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ language     : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ origin       : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ edition      : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ section      : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ subject      :List of 100
..$ coverage     :List of 100
..$ company      : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ industry     :List of 100
..$ infocode     :List of 100
..$ infodesc     :List of 100
..$ page         : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ wordcount    : int [1:100] NULL ...
..$ publisher    : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ rights       : chr [1:100]  ...
..$ text         : Named chr [1:100]  ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100]  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A late response for those interested.
The following code using `purrr::map` should return the tibble desired.

```
files_list <- list.files(Files_Path)
is_html_file <- str_extract(files_list, "\\w*\\.html")
html_files <- is_html_file[!is.na(is_html_file)] #Creates a list of all valid files in folder
html_files_path <- str_c(Files_Path, html_files)


html_files_path %>% 
  map(FactivaSource) %>% 
  map(Corpus, readerControl = list(language = NA)) %>% 
  map_dfr(tidy)
```